# Regex to replace everything after a specific symbol? java

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a string in format like "one / two / three" and I need only the first one (before the first foreslash). I tried it like that:

```
if (text.contains("/")) {
        int i = text.indexOf("/");
        return text.subSequence(0, i).toString();
    }
```

This solution works but I think it would be better to write simple `text.replace()` function.
Tried this regex `"\\/(.*)"` but it didn`t work.

Comment: Did you try splitting on a `/`?

Comment: Like this?`text.split("/")[0];`

Comment: Why would you want to replace? and why would you use `subSequence` instead of `substring` without making use of `toString()`?

Comment: Yes, split on a `/` and then join the second and the third part again https://ideone.com/NHlFZn

Comment: Using index and substring is fine (but cumbersome). But `split` ? That's just a lazy hack here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` doesn't take a regex as parameter but just tries to replace the passed char sequence.

You may use `replaceFirst`:

```
 return text.replaceFirst("/.*", "");
```

(note that there's nothing to escape and no group is necessary)

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you want something like `string.replace("/.*".toRegex(), "")`

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below code it will replace after first slash,

```
 text.replaceAll("\\/[^\\/].*", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

replace will not work in this case use this .

```
return text.replaceAll("/.", "");
```